# Pillow error when using get_rendition with CMYK JPEGs

Tags: django, python-imaging-library, wagtail

We have a custom endpoint in our Wagtail site which makes image renditions to be used in another site/admin.

it uses this line

```
rendition = the_image.get_rendition(filter + "|format-jpeg|jpegquality-80")
```

Locally With Wagtail 1.13.1 and pillow 5.0.0 it's fine, the error only happens in production where pillow is at 2.8.2. If Wagtail manages the pillow dependency, should it be enforcing a minimum version?

Is this a bug/issue or is Wagtail not suppose to manage dependencies in that way? I can just add a pillow>=5.0.0 in my production requirements file to fix it, so maybe that's fine?

The error is :

```
IOError: encoder error -2 when writing image file

django/core/handlers/exception.py in inner at line 41

response = get_response(request)
django/core/handlers/base.py in _legacy_get_response at line 249

response = self._get_response(request)
django/core/handlers/base.py in _get_response at line 187

response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
django/core/handlers/base.py in _get_response at line 185

response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, 
**callback_kwargs)
foxsite/views/views.py in get_image_filename at line 32

rendition = the_image.get_rendition(filter + "|format-
jpeg|jpegquality-80")
wagtail/wagtailimages/models.py in get_rendition at line 271

generated_image = filter.run(self, BytesIO())
wagtail/wagtailimages/models.py in run at line 404

return willow.save_as_jpeg(output, quality=quality, progressive=True, 
optimize=True)
willow/plugins/pillow.py in save_as_jpeg at line 74

image.save(f, 'JPEG', quality=quality, **kwargs)
PIL/Image.py in save at line 1693

save_handler(self, fp, filename)
PIL/JpegImagePlugin.py in _save at line 697

ImageFile._save(im, fp, [("jpeg", (0, 0)+im.size, 0, rawmode)], 
bufsize)
PIL/ImageFile.py in _save at line 486

raise IOError("encoder error %d when writing image file" % s)
```

Thanks

Joss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifying `pillow>=5.0.0` is indeed a valid way to address this.

Generally, Wagtail will try to specify as broad a range of versions as possible when using dependencies such as Pillow, in case there's some reason why people can't upgrade to the latest version (for example, a library might drop support for an older version of Python that they're currently using). In this case, Wagtail is *broadly* compatible with versions of Pillow as far back as 2.6. (I say 'broadly' because older versions may well have bugs that are outside of Wagtail's control, as with the one you've seen here - unfortunately it's not really possible for the Wagtail project to catch these changes, as it would require constantly monitoring Pillow's changelog to spot any bugfixes that might impact Wagtail users.)

Having said that, the 2.x branch of Pillow is now sufficiently outdated that, on balance, it's better to encourage users to upgrade, so I've now [updated Wagtail to require 4.x or above](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/commit/46286e2c8488e3067ddc33d300762b83351775d2).

Comment: Since putting pillow to 5.0.0 we've now started getting IOError: cannot write mode RGBA as JPEG , which occurs when a PNG wirh an alpha channel is converted to a JPEG I think. Pinning pillow to 4.1.1 seems to fix this. Just thought I'd mention it here.